# Azure diagnostics Keyword, Message, Task filed are empty with Write Event method in WAD table

Tags: azure, cloud, diagnostics

I have two event sources and specified in the ETWProviders of WADCFG config file for my PaaS migration project.

Logging for AuditEventSource is working but not working for TraceEventSource.
The major columns message, KeyWordName, TaskName are empty.

If any one has solution, Please let me know.

Comment: I have custom keyword class and the keywords are always setting as None when I was debugging local Azure emulator.

Comment: I have the same issue. Sadly I can not find solution yet.